# Display image original size, if possible, else shrink

Tags: css, background-image

There are lots of questions on this general subject, but none that do what I need.

I need to present multiple images, each in a `div` of its own, but I have no prior knowledge of whether they're portrait, landscape, or low resolution. What I want to do is show them original size (and centered) if they will fit (i.e. I don't want to stretch a low-resolution image), but if they're larger than the `div` then shrink them appropriately according to their aspect ratio.

This sounds simple but I gave up with the `img` element, and solutions suggesting `width:100%;height:auto;` were neglecting the fact that this presumes a landscape image.

I started using background properties and had much more success. If I could make this work then it would have the added benefit that it worked with IE11 too. For instance:

```css
background-image: url("http://example.jpg");
background-position:center center;
background-size: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

works fine if the image is smaller than the `div`, but crops the image if the original size is too large.

Is there a way to scale the size appropriately in this case (as with `background-size:contain`), but display original size when possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want with a combination of the two properties: `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  border: 1px solid;
  
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

1st item: image is smaller, keeps its original size.
2nd item: image is landscape, shrinked to fit.
3rd item: image is portrait, shrinked to fit.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: That's very promising. I hadn't tried 'flex'. It seems to me that my requirement is a fairly obvious one, and yet a solution is far from obvious. I tried your suggestion with IE11 and it was sticking scrollbars all over. Any idea which bit of the functionality it does not support?

Comment: In IE, "Min and max size declarations are ignored when wrapping flex items" - https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-11

Comment: If you have to support IE, you can achieve what you want with positioning properties that are supported by IE. Check this bin: https://jsbin.com/vahikim/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to crash IE11 trying it, and then realised that my test sample had been changed to use embed rather than img (I was trying anything at all before), and then it work. Excellent!